# iterate over python object's property via 'dir(object)' failed in defined ones

Tags: python

note:I use jupyter notebook and python 3.6

I create a class `myclass` and added two attributes `var1`,`var2`:

```
class myclass():
    def __init__(self):    
        self.var1 = 1
        self.var2 = 2

cls = myclass()
print(dir(cls))
```

Output:

```
['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__module__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 'var1',
 'var2']
```

and I have tested that
`cls.var1 == 1`
`cls.var2 == 2` are both true.

When trying get value of `'var1'` and `'var2'` of `cls` object with code below:

```
for attr in dir(cls):
    if not attr.startswith('__'):
        print(attr)
        print(cls[attr])
```

Output:

```
var1
[ignore traceback details...]
AttributeError: 'myclass' object has no attribute 'attr'
```

but `attr` is already `var1` according to first line of output, why was AttributeError raised when evaluate `cls[attr]`?

Comment: You want `getattr(cls, attr)` this isn't javascript :).  Also conventionally `cls` refers to a type but you have assigned an instance.

Comment: Tks,but. Why is cls.var1==1 is True, After I assigned var1 to attr, evaluate cls.attr gets attrbute error

Comment: `cls.attr` is looking literally for the an attribute named `'attr'`, if you want to get an attribute whose name is the value of `attr`, you need `getattr(cls, attr)` (as I originally stated)

Comment: @AnthonySottile got it thanks